# How to set a path once and use it throughout my javascript program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm building an electron-app which uses a database. The problem: every time I need to add new code, I need to create a connection to the database. I do it this way:

`let db = new sqlite3.Database('./appdata/resources/protodatabase.evv');`

Is there a way to create a global variable or something similar which holds this filepath? So I don't have to hardcode the filepath in the program?

Comment: Yeah, you make an object that manages your database connection(s), and then you require/import it everywhere you need. Don't think about putting things in global scope, instead think "putting things in objects that you can import"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onload application, you can save the `path` in `localstorage`, provided by `JavaScript`

this can help you!

```
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
  // Retrieve
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! Didn't use it though ;) I eventually created a global var that contained the link. I can call it from anywhere, which makes is more pratical :) For example: ```var databaselocation = './appdata/resources/protodatabase.evv';```